# Two subsequent show()s on dataframe resulting in inconsistent results

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In spark/pyspark I have some code that build a dataframe by union()ing multiple dataframes:

```
master_df = None
for k, files in key_to_parquet_files.items():
   df = read_parquet(*files)
   df = df.select(['ID']).withColumn('foo', F.lit(k))
   if master_df is None:
       master_df = df
   else:
       master_df = master_df.union(df)
```

At this point, many rows will have a common ID field. Then I run code like this

```
master_df = master_df.dropDuplicates(['ID'])
print_ids_df = master_df.filter(F.col("ID").isin(*["A", "B", "C"])).orderBy(F.col('ID'))
print_ids_df.show()
print_ids_df = master_df.filter(F.col("ID").isin(*["A", "B", "C"])).orderBy(F.col('ID'))
print_ids_df.show()
```

Low and behold both show() commands result in a different value for foo. This makes no sense to me. I understand if I run the entire code twice, yes, the outputs can be different between runs, but both shows() in the same run should always be the same. Am I out to lunch?

In fact, anytime you do any operation on master_df with relation to ID, the result is always inconsistent.

## EDIT:

Thanks for the answers. I now understand. Data engineering concepts are not obvious, at first, for someone coming from synchronous programming languages. That said, I used the following code to make the dropDuplicates deterministic, and it works as expected.

```
master_df_window = Window.partitionBy(['ID']).orderBy(F.col('foo').asc_nulls_last())
master_df = master_df.withColumn('rank', F.row_number().over(master_df_window)).filter(F.col('rank') == 1)
```

This code needs to happen before dropDuplicates to make sure the dataframe is sorted by ID.

Comment: The output would be the same if you were to call `show()` twice on the same dataset. You are not. Although the expressions may be the same, differences in underlying hash values may lead to different final ordering. Keep in mind that even `master_df` itself may differ between the two calls unless you `cache()` it since it will be recomputed from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark do computation in **parallel**, the data will be divided into **multiple partitions**, each partition will be processed separately from other partitions, the result then is the result of the process of all the partitions.

In your case you are doing a .show() which will bring results together to show it to the user, so the final result will be the result of all partitions, when spark load/transform data, the records will be processed in random order because no order was specified, so you get the  same results but in different order that's normal.

If you are getting different results, that means your code is not deterministic, weird, huh? Not really, in your code there's a dropDuplicates which will drop duplicates values for the ID column, but there's no order for the foo column, so  it will remove duplicates values in any order of execution, for example for key (ID, foo) = (10, 1), (10, 2) in some cases it will drop the first row and some cases it will drop the second row.  Also, since spark is lazy it will re-run twice the same code, which will lead to different results each time.

So in conclusion: if your code is deterministic you will get the same results each time but in different order because spark process data in parallel, if your code is not deterministic you my get different results for each execution.

Answer (score 1):

`Union` is a lazy operation, after the for loop do, `master_df.cache()` and check again